# How do I exportToExcel a calculated column in jqgrid? exportToExcel virtual column

Tags: jqgrid, export, export-to-excel, calculated-columns

The excel export for col3 in the jsfiddle jqgrid below contains no data.

Does anyone know how to get the data to exportToExcel for virtual or calculated columns?

http://jsfiddle.net/carboncope/7rcsaepo/15/

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
datatype: "local",
data: mydata,
height: 250,
width: 500,
colNames: ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
pager: "#gridpager",
colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
    },
    {
        name: 'col1',
        index: 'col1',
        width: 50,
    },
    {
        name: 'col2',
        index: 'col2',
        width: 50
    },
    {
        name: 'col3',
        index: 'col3',
        width: 50,
        formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            var showValue = (parseInt(rowObject.col1) + parseInt(rowObject.col2));
            if (showValue) {
                if (options.isExported) {
                    return showValue;
                } else {
                    return showValue;
                }
            } else {
                return 'novalue';
            }
        },
    }
],
caption: "exportToExcel Calculated Column",
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was a bug in the code. The problem is [fixed](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/c12aad51dc8d04637d6f0482ec58d1e52a128629) and the fixed code can be get from GitHub

Comment: @carboncope, Thank you - glad to help